# Unable to load images on iphone, for android device code works properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

```
sortable.map(function (item, index) {
      var mapsThumbImage = sortable[index].maps.small !== null ? sortable[index].maps.small : null;
      serialNumber = serialNumber + 1;
      sharedRidesData.push(
        <TouchableOpacity key={`${serialNumber}`} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RidesDetails', {
          tripID: sortable[index].id, friendScreenFriendShipUserID: this.state.friendScreenFriendShipUserID, previousScreen:
            AppConstants.screenNameProfile
        })}>
          <View style={styles.ridesDataView} key={`${serialNumber}`}>
            <View style={styles.ridesFixedBoxViewDesignFirst} key={`${serialNumber}`}>
              <View style={styles.ridesViewRidesDesign} key={`${serialNumber}`}>
                <View style={styles.ridesViewRidesMarginDesign} key={`${serialNumber}`}>
                  <View style={styles.ridesMiddleBoxScrollViewImageDesign}>
                    {/* {mapsThumbImage != null ?
                      <Image source={{ uri: mapsThumbImage }} style={styles.ridesProfileImageDesign} />
                      : null} */}
                    {mapsThumbImage !== null ? <Image source={{ uri: mapsThumbImage }} style={styles.ridesProfileImageDesign} /> : null}
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.boxLastContentViewDesignRiderLeftContentInnerViewFavourites} key={`${serialNumber}`}>
                    {this.state.fontLoaded ? <Text style={[styles.ridesOriginDestinationTextFavourites1, { fontSize: favouritesOrgDestTextFontSize, }]}>{sortable[index].origin.name} to</Text> : null}
                    {this.state.fontLoaded ? <Text style={[styles.ridesOriginDestinationTextFavourites2, { fontSize: favouritesOrgDestTextFontSize, }]}>{sortable[index].destination.name}</Text> : null}
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.boxLastContentViewDesignRiderRightContentInnerViewFavourites}>
                    {this.state.fontLoaded ? <Text style={styles.ridesCountDesignRiderTextFavourites}>{sortable[index].trip_count}</Text> : null}
                    {this.state.fontLoaded ? <Text style={[styles.ridesCountDesignRidesTextTypeFavourites, { fontSize: RidesDetailsFavouriteTabDateDifferenceFontSize, }]} > Rides</Text> : null}
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.boxLastContentViewDesignFriendsMainView}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }) }} style={styles.checkBoxAgreeTermsAndConditionOuterDesign}>
                      <Entypo size={25} name="chevron-small-right" color="#292929" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }.bind(this));
```

**API Response:**

```
{"sortable": [
        {
            "id": 5673,
            "trip_count": 66,
            "origin": {
                "id": 806,
                "name": "Name1",
                "lat": "40.70823502",
                "lng": "-74.00530063"
            },
            "destination": {
                "id": 812,
                "name": "Name2",
                "lat": "40.722055",
                "lng": "-73.989111"
            },
            "maps": {
                "thumb": "paththumb.png",
                "small": "pathsmall.png",
                "large": "pathlarge.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5035,
            "trip_count": 64,
            "origin": {
                "id": 1545,
                "name": "Name3",
                "lat": null,
                "lng": null
            },
            "destination": {
                "id": 865,
                "name": "Name4",
                "lat": "40.72243797",
                "lng": "-74.00566443"
            },
            "maps": {
                "thumb": null,
                "small": null,
                "large": null
            }
        }]
}
```

Here, **sortable[index].maps.small** is a server image path I am getting.
If image will not be there on the server then API response will be null for image.

The issue is, all images loads in Android device and unable load in iphone devices.

I also have console log all the images, and I have got proper path of images.
If image will not exist then nothing should be happened.

How to resolve this issue?
Would anybody suggest me?
Thank You.